# Get User Information while Authenticating from Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I have a web forms application which I developed for testing Authentication/Authorization scenarios. While creating the test project, I selected "No Authentication" which created my project to have no authentication mechanism code. I published the web site to my azure tenant and enabled the Azure Active Directory Authentication from the "Authentication / Authorization" under features. I created an Azure AD app pointing to my web application. After hitting the default page, the app now authenticates and everything seems to work fine.

However, when I run the app locally from within Visual Studio, I am not able to get the user information as there are no appropriate headers available, eg X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME. My next step was to call the graph API to get the detailed user information.

**NOTE**: I am able to include the OWIN code in my web project to authenticate users, but I want minimal code change to my existing on-prem windows authentication application.

Any help / guidance

Comment: are you looking at a single sign on experience for the app when used from intranet as well as internet ?  then you need to look at azure AD connect.  in case of azure AD you will use graph API to authenticate and get user info etc in the on premises AD you will use LDAP.

Comment: Single sign on may not be desired as I already requesting my user to input his/her AD login credentials when browsing the site. I wish to authenticate the user via Azure AD. However, when I run the app from VS, I am not able to get either the Auth Headers not am I able to get the claims principal for calling Graph API.

Comment: you have simply linked the app to AAD. the default page takes you to the live login page and you proceed from there. generally the practice is to Add the  authentication/Authorization ADAL  calls using graph API in the [Authorize] attribute of controllers in the case of MVC app. Then use the user information got using graph API wherever you need them.

Comment: Mine is a web forms apps. Do you have a sample code that displays how to get user information form graph api via auth token?

Comment: graph api works with objectId which is the unique id for the user in AAD.wonder if auth token will have that. u need to check it out. graph api code is same for all types of applications.

Comment: Ok. So Object ID is returned in the header as "X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID". I'll see if I can pass on that ObjectID to graph api and get the required groups information. However, this header is only returned when you host your app on Azure and enable the Authentication/Authorization feature. I was thinking if I could get a way I can get this info from within Visual Studio.

Comment: it should work anywhere. hosting in azure alone does not really matter. or may be you should register the local app in AAD or something. explore that option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, when I run the app locally from within Visual Studio, I am not able to get the user information as there are no appropriate headers available, eg X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME. My next step was to call the graph API to get the detailed user information.

This is expected. The X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME header (and related headers) is added by the Authentication / Authorization module which runs in app service. when you run locally from Visual Studio, you won't have this module and thus won't have this request header.

If you want to use the same code both locally and in App Service, instead of looking at the request headers, I suggest using .NET APIs which surface up user information, such as **ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.Name**. This should be populated correctly whether you're using Windows Authentication locally or Authentication / Authorization in Azure App Service.

You can find more information about the underlying mechanics of Authentication / Authorization here: https://cgillum.tech/2016/02/01/architecture-of-azure-app-service-authentication-authorization/.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you point me to a code sample using ClaimsPrincipal for getting user group information via Graph API?

Comment: Here is the Graph API documentation for getting group information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#get-all-group-memberships-transitive. Here is some information about how to call into the Graph API as a user (specific to Authentication / Authorization): https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/25/app-service-auth-aad-graph-api/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the assist. I was successfully able to fetch the required information via headers. However, a couple of questions. 
1) Is there a way I can populate the header information, like token, refresh token etc. as well in ClaimsPrincipal? 
2) There are a couple of times I have seen that whenever I modify the config/authSettings via resource manager, I start getting error as "You are not authorized to view this page". I verified that the json file I edited is in correct format with all syntax in place. I had to delete the website, recreate it and make the changes again.

Comment: For 1) are you asking if you can do it in your code? If so, sure - you can add anything you want into the ClaimsPrincipal.

Example:
((ClaimsIdentity)ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("TestClaim", "TestValue"));

For 2) I've not heard of this problem before. Does the Azure portal continue to work for your site when this happens?

Comment: For 1) I mean instead of I using CliamsPrincipal for user group info while working on-prem and using headers to fetch token for calling graph api to fetch group info, is there a way I can directly get the token and refresh token automatically set in claimsprincipal? The way we got header information populated via modification in json from resource explorer. For 2) I tried a couple of times after I got this error. So I deleted the web app and recreated it and all worked fine. I'll try to reproduce this issue again.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to automatically have the tokens appear as claims in the ClaimsPrincipal.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the confirmation.